# casting text to date in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have saved date as text type. There are a few invalid dates those are preventing me from running any date related operation. For e.g.

```
select case when deliver_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then '2014-01-01' else deliver_date::date end as new_date, count(*) as cnt  from some_table group by new_date
Error in query: ERROR: Error converting text to date
```

I am using the following work-around that seems to be working.

```
select left(deliver_date,10) as new_date, count(*) as cnt  from sms_dlr group by new_date
```

But I will like to know if it is possible to convert this column to date.

Comment: Another good reason to store dates as DATE and not as text...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error when the invalid date is of value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (Your original query works as intended). Are you sure there aren't any other invalid values, like '' ?

Comment: Yes. There is text like 'abc' in the same date column. My problem is how to convert that text to a date for e.g. '2014-01-01'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dropping the `::date` part:

```
select
    cast(
        case
            when deliver_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then '2014-01-01'
            else deliver_date
        end
        as date
    ) as new_date,
    count(*) as cnt
from some_table
group by new_date
```

Comment: This solution won't work if you need to run date-related operations, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate the valid and invalid date values.

One solution is to use regular expressions- I'll let you decide how thorough you want to be, but this will broadly cover date and datetime values:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN 
        deliver_date SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' 
        OR deliver_date SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'  
    THEN TO_DATE(deliver_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ELSE TO_DATE('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    END as new_date,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM some_table
GROUP BY new_date
```

Comment: This worked for me with a slight mod - note, my date data was 20170111 so instead of `TO_DATE(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` I needed `TO_DATE(date, 'YYYYMMDD')` the documentation  [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html) is pretty sparse